# Can find Class Name using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

Below is a snippet of the HTML using `page_source` method in selenium.

Why can't I find className `cell-content cell-colshopCapacity` ?

`'<div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner" style="text-align:left;">Daily</div></td><td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-templatecolumn-1065 x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable "><div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner" style="text-align:left;"><span class="cell-content cell-colshopCapacity">101</span></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div><div class="x-container save x-container-default x-box-layout-ct" style="padding: 5px 15px 18px 9px; width: 907px;"`

Using the below returns an empty list `[]`

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'path/to/chromedriver')
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('cell-content cell-colshopCapacity')
```

If I use `driver.page_source` in vs code it returns the HTML from the webpage which is how I was able to produce the above snippet. Am I correct in assuming if `driver.page_source` returns HTML with the said class name then I should be able to find it using the below, given that if it was in another `frame` then it wouldn't return the class name I am trying to find? Or do I have that assumption wrong?

`driver.find_elements_by_class_name('cell-content cell-colshopCapacity')`

Comment: I know nothing about selenium/webdriver. However, if you know how to get the HTML then I recommend that you try BeautifulSoup to navigate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class name do not work with spaces in Selenium.

so try changing that to `css_selector` instead :

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.cell-content.cell-colshopCapacity')
```